# PHP How can I sort a 2D array which consist of sequence of integers (dynamic length)?

Tags: php, arrays

Say for example I have several arrays, and I need to sort them in order of their sequence:

```
$list[0] = array(1,2,3,5);
$list[1] = array(1,2,4,6,8);
$list[2] = array(1,2,3,4,9);
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
$list[2] = array(1,2,3,4,9);
$list[0] = array(1,2,3,5);
$list[1] = array(1,2,4,6,8);
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve such result without having to utilize a lot of foreach loops?
By the way, the array are tree routes, I'm trying to find the left most branch of the tree.

---

I've looked at some of the answers, but its only correct up to a certain degree. When it starts sorting double or triple digit integer, then it fails (most probably because it consider the list as a string rather than individual integers; or the sequence might not be in descending order).

Try sorting these list and you'll see why:

```
$list[0] = array(1,2,5);
$list[1] = array(1,2,4,14);
$list[2] = array(1,2,4,15);
```

OR

```
$list[0] = array(1,2,5);
$list[1] = array(1,2,4,14,9);
$list[2] = array(1,2,4,15,8);
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your result is the same as the input. You rearranged the rows, but the indexes stayed with the same values.

Comment: I can't think of a good way that doesn't require writing a custom comparison function that uses a loop, and then use `usort` with that function.

Comment: Yes, Barmar, the indexes is supposed to stayed with the same values, just merely rearranging the rows...

Comment: Then it's not really sorting, because if you traverse the array with `for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)` it will use the original order.

Comment: Can there be negative numbers?

Comment: Yeah, come to think of it, its not merely sorting, it can be out of order as well... I'll need to figure a way to read each element of the array and compare against the rest of the list (on the same column) and take the lower value of the compared pairs.

I'm only interested in finding the result of the sorted first row only though. All positive integers >= 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/es/function.uasort.php) function, which maintains indexes and only reorders the array elements:

```
uasort($list, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(implode('-', $a), implode('-', $b));
});
```

The [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strcmp.php) function compares two strings and return -1 if former is first, 0 if equal, and 1 if latter is first.

Beware with the [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), it works only with PHP >= 5.3.

Comment: This will treat `array(1, 2, 3)` and `array(123)` as equal. You could add a delimiter, to fix that, but it won't do the right thing with negative numbers.

Comment: Good point @Barmar, answer edited. About negative numbers, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: He said there are no negative numbers, so it looks like this should work.